# Handling TAX with PayPal tax variable

Tags: php, paypal

In `PHP` I do a simple calculation. Where we are, tax (`GST`) is charged at `10%`. So, What I'm doing in my php code is:

```
$a=$_REQUEST["amount"]; // this contains 504.95
$amount = $a*.10;
```

BUT, When I click "Purchase" and it takes me to PayPal, instead of showing up with order details, PayPal says:

> "The link you have used to enter the
>   PayPal system contains an incorrectly
>   formatted item amount."

Here's what I've tried:

I have tried making a purchase WITHOUT tax. And it worked.

I have tried making a purchase with a value of `504` INSTEAD OF `504.95` and it worked.

So, how can I charge `10%` tax on `504.95`?

Here's my code:

```
$amnt = $_REQUEST['amount'];
    $amount = $amnt*.10;

$p->add_field('tax', $amount);
```

Any help at all is appreciated.
Thank you

UPDATE:

Okay,

So I think I may have figured out how to get the right way to send the data, by using

```
number_format($price*0.10);
```

But, it's not calculating properly on the paypal webpage!

I have a sample item priced at `$504.85`, and it is supposed to be taxed `10%`.

But PayPal is only charging `$50` (that does not equal `10%`)

**What the!?**

Comment: This sounds like you are setting the item number (which must be an integer for obvious reasons), not the price (which should support decimal numbers).

Comment: BTW, I would store the tax value in a constant so you can change it - it's bound to change at some point, and you'll have a hell of a time grepping all occurrences of `.10` in your project

Comment: Sorry Pekka, I don't get what you mean by "setting the item number". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Lucifer what does `$p->add_field` actually add to the HTML code? Can you show the end result? (Assuming you are generating a Paypal button of some sort) BTW: Use `@username`, then people will see your reply in their inbox

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, I always wondered why people used @. There is no PayPal "button" perse. It's just a page that receives or $_GET's info from a form on the previous page, then submits it to paypal. I got the script from: http://www.micahcarrick.com   - As it's the only one I could get to work (my first time integrating paypal)

Comment: @Lucifer okay, but you need to show the generated results. It is generating either HTML or the URL for a GET request, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, url for get request. I was about to copy/paste it here for you, but I thought of something and thought I'd try that first, and it worked. It was a problem with the formatting of the thingy. :-) Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok cool, I've got it.

I am now using:

```
$amnt = $_REQUEST['amount'];
$ship = $_REQUEST['freight'];
$comb = $amnt+$ship;
$amount = $comb*0.10;
$p->add_field('tax', number_format($amount,2,'.',''));
```

And it works perfectly. Thanks!